# How do I listen to key presses in a Mac Catalyst app?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mac-catalyst

I have a simple iOS game that I am porting to Mac. I would like for the user to be able to control the game using their keyboard. There is not native text input (like `UITextField`, `UITextView`).

How do I listen to key down events in a Mac Catalyst app? It does not seem trivial.

`UIKeyCommand` does not work because it seems to be made for combinations (e.g. `cmd+c`). I could create a fake text field, but I am looking for a cleaner way to do this. I want to listen to single letters and numbers.

Can I integrate `NSResponder::keyDown(with:)` somehow?

Comment: be aware that in catalyst (2022) it seems presses are not passed on to child VCs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just override the pressesBegan method. Here is the sample code I use in my game to control a player. It uses *UIKeyCommand* for special command keys like the Arrow keys and *key.character* to react on a special character. 
The original code comes from the [Apple Catalyst Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/handling_key_presses_made_on_a_physical_keyboard).

```
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {

    var didHandleEvent = false
    for press in presses {
        guard let key = press.key else { continue }
        if key.charactersIgnoringModifiers == UIKeyCommand.inputLeftArrow || key.characters == "a" {
            self.moveLeft(self)
            didHandleEvent = true
        } else if key.charactersIgnoringModifiers == UIKeyCommand.inputRightArrow || key.characters == "d" {
            self.moveRight(self)
            didHandleEvent = true
        } else if key.charactersIgnoringModifiers == UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow || key.characters == "w" {
            self.moveForward(self)
            didHandleEvent = true
        } else if key.charactersIgnoringModifiers == UIKeyCommand.inputDownArrow || key.characters == "s" {
            self.moveBackward(self)
            didHandleEvent = true
        } else if key.characters == "q" {
            self.turnLeft(self)
            didHandleEvent = true
        } else if key.characters == "e" {
            self.turnRight(self)
            didHandleEvent = true
        }
    }

    if didHandleEvent == false {
        // Didn't handle this key press, so pass the event to the next responder.
        super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
    }
}
```